# Выравнивание одного элемента в display: table

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с тем, что из шести элементов table-cell, обернутых в div-блок table, один - стабильно отображается с небольшим смещением по вертикали. Тестовые поля и два выпадающих списка выводятся корректно, дата - на пару пикселей ниже общего ряда.

Пробовал выравнивать элементы без таблицы вообще (с переносом строки), добавлял display: inline, пробовал вводить отдельный класс  для проблемного поля и менять margin-bottom - результат тот же самый. Отступы меняются, порядок меняется, смещение остаётся.

```css
input, select {
      size: 150px;
      height: 30px;
      font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: none;
    }

    .main-form {display: table;}

    .input {display: table-cell;}

    .select {display: table-cell;}
```

```html
<div class="main-form">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="input"><input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="input"><input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="input"><input class="date" type="date" name="birthDate" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="input"><input type="number" name="passNumber" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="select"><select name="sex" required="true"></select></div>
        <div class="select"><select name="nationality" required="true"></select></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы до текущего момента используете устаревший формат вёрстки, то вам необходимо изучить всё заново, в противном случае вы в дальнейшем столкнётесь со многими проблемами, а ваши знакомые/коллеги/сверстники будут всегда выше вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько помню, `display: table-cell` "работает" если его родитель `display: table`, а у вас получается

```
<div> <!-- С display: table -->
  <form> <!-- Который по дефолту display: block -->
    <div> <!-- и пошли div'ы с  display: table-cell -->
```

Если учитывать то, что написано выше + добавить для `table-cell` правило `vertical-align: middle` то всё работает.

```css
input,
select {
  size: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.main-form > form {
  display: table;
  height: 200px;
}

.input, .select {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-form">
  <form method="post">
    <div class="input"><input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="..."></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="..."></div>
    <div class="input"><input class="date" type="date" name="birthDate" placeholder="..."></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="number" name="passNumber" placeholder="..."></div>
    <div class="select">
      <select name="sex" required="true"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="select">
      <select name="nationality" required="true"></select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

По крайней мере тут, в сниппете, и через мазилу.

Answer (score 0):

```
input, select {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```css
input,
select {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.p0 input,
.p0 select {
  padding: 0;
}


.p1 input[type="text"],
.p1 input[type="number"],
.p1 input:not([type]),
.p1 select {
  padding: 2.5px 0;
}
```

```html
default:<br>

<input type="text" value="AJja">
<input type="number" value="145">
<input type="date" value="05/05/2009">
<select>
  <option selected>AJja</option>
</select>

<hr>

padding="0":<br>

<div class="p0">
  <input type="text" value="AJja">
  <input type="number" value="145">
  <input type="date" value="05/05/2009">
  <select>
    <option selected>AJja</option>
  </select>
</div>


<hr>

padding fix for some inputs. <br>
Note: for other font size other padding needed:<br>

<div class="p1">
  <input type="text" value="AJja">
  <input type="number" value="145">
  <input type="date" value="05/05/2009">
  <select>
    <option selected>AJja</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло. Смещение осталось.

Comment: дайте ссылку на живой сайт с этими элементами. Код в сниппете запускал - все отлично.

А в общем проблема у вас с тем ,что инпуты разных типов имеют разные способы отрисовки относительно линий шрифта. По умолчанию инпуты - это инлайн-элементы, которые должны быть выровнены по базовой линии окружающего текста, а их границы могут вылезать за него как угодно. У некоторых типов инпутов есть паддинги, у некоторых - нет.  Добавил в код чуток для справки.

Comment: Живого сайта нет, только репозиторий https://github.com/anabiozzze/AviaSale/blob/master/target/classes/templates/index.html. Вообще да, на второй странице сейчас то же самое, так что буду каждое поле отдельно отрисовывать и ровнять, видимо.

Comment: а вообще, зачем вам этот геморрой? используйте нормальный `flex`.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно дабавить отступ классу date
  input, .date{padding:1px 0}

```css
input, select {
      size: 150px;
      height: 30px;
      font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: none;
    }

    .main-form {display: table;}

    .input {display: table-cell;}

    .select {display: table-cell;}
  input, .date{padding:1px 0}
```

```html
<div class="main-form">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="input"><input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="input"><input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="input"><input class="date" type="date" name="birthDate" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="input"><input type="number" name="passNumber" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="select"><select name="sex" required="true"></select></div>
        <div class="select"><select name="nationality" required="true"></select></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но не помогло.=)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-form form {
  display: flex;
}

input, select {
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-form">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="input"><input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="input"><input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="input"><input class="date" type="date" name="birthDate" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="input"><input type="number" name="passNumber" placeholder="..."></div>
        <div class="select">
            <select name="sex" required="true">
                <option value='0'>test</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="select">
            <select name="sex" required="true">
                <option value='0'>test</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```